# BadImageFormatException error after upgrading to .NET 472

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Following on from an upgrade from .NET 461 to 472, when I attempt to run my project, I am getting the error message below

I have cleaned/rebuilt my project. I have deleted the `bin` and `obj` folders all with no luck

Is there anything I need to do with NuGet or remove any `<dependantAssembly>` property from the web.config file?

> [BadImageFormatException: Cannot load a reference assembly for
>   execution.]
>
> [BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.IO.Compression' or one of its dependencies. Reference
>   assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be
>   loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131058)]    System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName
>   fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly
>   locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder,
>   Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +0
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +36
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +152
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr
>   pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection) +21    System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString) +28
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.IO.Compression' or one of its dependencies. Reference
>   assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be
>   loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131058)]
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +726
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()
>   +196    System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo
>   ai) +45
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection
>   compConfig) +172
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies()
>   +91    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String
>   preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +111
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +156
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +695
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.IO.Compression' or one of its dependencies. Reference
>   assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be
>   loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131058)]    System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext
>   context) +659
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +89
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +188

Comment: What is the build platform for your solution ?  Any CPU or x86 or x64 or anything else ?

Comment: @ManojChoudhari it is "Any CPU"

Comment: Can you retry uninstalling an dinstalling the `system.io.compression` dependency ?